# How to make kill command faster

Tags: linux, performance, kernel, ipc

I have two processes running in two different cores and no any other user processes are running on these cores. Now I am trying to stop one process from another process by sending **kill -STOP** and **kill -CONT** in loop. But the **kill -STOP** command is taking more than 200 micro seconds to stop the process. Is there any way to reduce this time to less than 5 micro seconds

Comment: `sudo kill -9 process_id         // dispose the process by 'process_id' id`

Comment: Put the receiving process in the realtime scheduling class maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo kill -9 process_id
```

Hope this helps.